# How to map query to non-entity class + entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I know how to do query to resultClass mapping in IBatis.

How can I map the native query result to the object that is a mix of entity class and scalars in hibernate ? How can I set the parameters ?

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Hibernate `Session` API, you can do it by comining `addEntity()` and `addScalar()` methods:

```
Query q = s.createSQLQuery(
    "select p.*, count(e.id) as c " +
    "from Project p left join Employee e on p.id = e.project_id " +
    "group by p.id")
    .addEntity(Project.class).addScalar("c");
```

In JPA you can do it with `@SqlResultSetMapping`:

```
@SqlResultSetMappings(
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "projectWithCount"
        entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = Project.class),
        columns = @ColumnResult(name = "c")))

...

Query q = s.createSQLQuery(
        "...", "projectWithCount")
```

Comment: I am new to @SqlResultSetMappings, so can you also tell which class will this annotation entry go to? Will this annotation go into a class which is not an entity class and has 2 properties: 1 pointing to Project class and 1 pointing to int c; ?